# Why is there a borrow error when no borrowing overlap is occurring?

Tags: rust, borrow

The following [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c1dcd508efafb64bddb6db65ac15eaf1) fails with a borrow error:

```
extern crate chrono; // 0.4.6

fn main() {
    let mut now = chrono::Local::today();
    now = std::mem::replace(&mut now, now.succ());
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `now` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/lib.rs:5:39
  |
5 |     now = std::mem::replace(&mut now, now.succ());
  |           ----------------- --------  ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
  |           |                 |
  |           |                 mutable borrow occurs here
  |           mutable borrow later used by call
```

Why is there a borrow error here? [`now.succ()`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.6/chrono/naive/struct.NaiveDate.html#method.succ) returns a new object, and it would look like the `succ()` call should return the new object, end the immutable borrow before the mutable borrow occurs with `replace`.

Comment: I think order matter. But anyway, you already have the solution

Comment: Yes, the question is not how to fix it. It's why it's an error at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the arguments matters. For example this works:

```rust
/// Same as `std::mem::replace`, but with the reversed parameter order.
pub fn replace<T>(src: T, dest: &mut T) -> T {
    std::mem::replace(dest, src)
}

fn main() {
    let mut now = chrono::Local::today();
    now = replace(now.succ(), &mut now);
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=292464e80c3aad1c9225e07071e87ab6))

But in your example, `&mut now` appears first, and when evaluating the second parameter, it is already borrowed.

Comment: Why `now = replace(now.succ(), &mut now);` ? look strange xd it's a do nothing line

Comment: That would be a compiler limitation then.

Comment: @Stargateur it never even crossed my mind to make that example function work. I was even going to type `unimplemented`()` but got too lazy to do even this.

Comment: @Listerone while the order wouldn't actually matter for borrowing in this example, for more complex examples with different lifetimes and references, it could matter, so the compiler must at some point set a line.

Comment: @mcarton Is that really true?  Since the immutable borrow is a call that must return before replace can actually receive the mutable reference to now, is there _any_ scenario where these two could interact other than as expected?

Comment: I thought function call argument evaluation order was unspecified.

Comment: @hkBst in Rust it is specified, but even if it weren’t the borrow checker could be more constrained that the generated code.